# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx

Trying to deploy an application written in Rails and Angular.

I am getting 502 gateway timeout error in browser when i was sending the request through browser

when i checked the logs , i got this error:

```
2017/12/17 20:07:48 [error] 12347#12347: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.50.60.2, server: 10.12.4.245, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.12.4.245:80/favicon.ico", host: "10.12.4.242", referrer: "http://10.12.4.242/"
```

How can I fix it and please explain in detail.

Here is my configuration:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx.conf:

```
 upstream puma {
  server unix:///var/www/phonebook-api/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}
server {
listen   80 default;
listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;

server_name 10.12.4.245;
charset utf-8;
root /var/www/phonebook-api;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
root phonebook-app/dist;
index index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri @app;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
   location @app {
     proxy_pass        http://10.12.4.245;
     proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto http;
     proxy_set_header  Host $http_host  ;
     proxy_redirect    off;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    }

  client_max_body_size 50M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: If you SSH into the machine running NGINX are you able to make succesful requests to the server at 10.12.4.245? It looks like there just no connection from the NGINX server to the Rails server

Comment: Also, just include the second part of your NGINX config, you can remove the first part (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) it just distracting.

Comment: @qff, no, I can't go on this address gives an error message (113) No route to host

Comment: Either the server is down, or there's network setup issue (could be firewall). Could also be Rails listening on some other port than port 80. Check out https://superuser.com/a/1236451

Comment: @qff I run Puma on the socket (bundle exec puma -C config/pum)

Comment: Is NGINX and Rails/Puma running on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

open # file settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] 
to 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.btcdoller.com', 'btcdoller.com','206.189.113.168']

## Discover our IP address

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
to
ALLOWED_HOSTS += ip_addresses()

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have error in you app.js or index.js .First try to resolve that and try once again.